# ffmpeg how to use AMD hardware accelerated encoder?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i VID1.webm  -c:v  h264_amf VID1.mkv
```

results:

> Unknown encoder 'h264_amf'

```
./configure --enable-encoder=h264_amf
```

> WARNING: Disabled h264_amf_encoder because not all dependencies are
>   satisfied: amf

also tried vaapi

> WARNING: Disabled h264_vaapi_hwaccel because not all dependencies are
>   satisfied: vaapi WARNING: Disabled h264_vaapi_encoder because some
>   selected dependency is unsatisfied: cbs_h264 vaapi_encode

The enviroment : Ubuntu 18.10 , CPU AMD Ryzen 2700U.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment but doesn't fit easily as one:

You need amf header installed first: https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF (appears to be windows only?) update: ubuntu now supported? https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF/issues/4

this might help with vaapi https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/eb45d2e22afec7534f4a117d15fe6d89 but unclear if vaapi supports amd...